# function for change the image using keyboard arrow key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a gallery of images, I need to change the image when the user will press the arrow keys after the modal popup.

<kbd>left arrow</kbd> to change the image to the left and the <kbd>right arrow</kbd> for right. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I couldn't understand what function should I use to change the images to left and right.

**This is what I have tried so far:**

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      alert('left');
      break;
    case 39:
      alert('right');
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 779px;
  min-width: 779px;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: -10%;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width: 98%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width: 98%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: So call plusSlides(-1) and plusSlides(1) instead of the alert....

Answer (score 1):

I see your code there is no problem with the javascript your key down function should look like this

```
<pre>document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 37){ plusSlides(-1); }    //for left arrow
    if(e.keyCode === 39){ plusSlides(1) }     //for right arrow
});
</pre>
```

The Full Code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            margin: 0;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        img {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        /* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
        .container {
            position: relative;
        }

        /* Hide the images by default */
        .mySlides {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
        .cursor {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev,
        .next {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            width: auto;
            padding: 16px;
            margin-top: -50px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
        }

        /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        .next {
            right: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }

            /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
            .prev:hover,
            .next:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            }

        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }

        /* Container for image text */
        .caption-container {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 2px 16px;
            color: white;
        }

        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Six columns side by side */
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 16.66%;
        }

        /* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
        .demo {
            opacity: 0.6;
        }

            .active,
            .demo:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <h2 style="text-align:center">Slideshow Gallery</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

        <div class="caption-container">
            <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img class="demo cursor" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 37){ plusSlides(-1); }    //for left arrow
    if(e.keyCode === 39){ plusSlides(1) }     //for right arrow
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.